# Jar executed in eclipse but not running in Unix

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, unix

I have a Jar which is running in fine in eclipse and cmd prompt.
When i tried executing the same in Unix , it is not executing.

**Note:** Java version  in Unix is 1.5 ; Java version in eclipse is 1.7

```
java -jar text.jar
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad
>   version number in .class file
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered the question yourself. While compiled at 1.7 you try to execute the jar in an 1.5 environment. Update your Unix JRE to 1.7 and it should work.

Alternatively you can rebuild the jar at 1.5. In eclipse, right click at your project in the project browser => properties => java compiler => compiler compliance level.

Answer (score 1):

You get the `UnsupportedClassVersionError` when you are trying to run an application having a jar in the classpath that is built using a newer version than the one you are using at runtime.

Comment: what is the solution ?

Comment: Upgrade your machine to a newer Java version or build the jar using the older one, if the older one can compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you try to run a class that was compiled for a Java version newer than what you have; for example, if you try to use a class that was compiled for Java 6 or newer on a Java 5 JVM.

It doesn't necessarily have to be your own class; you might be using some library that was built for Java 6 or newer.

Are you using specific libraries (JAR files)? Check if these are compatible with Java 5 or not. Or upgrade your Java version to Java 6